# Closable tabitem. How to add textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, textbox

I'm working on a multithreaded application were a new "closable" tab is opened for each new thread. I got the code for closable tabitems from [this site](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1867-create-tab-control-wpf.aspx) but I also want to have a textbox in the tabitem. I tired adding the textbox during runtime from the main method, but it was not accessible from the thread which was created after. what is the best way to make this work? I'm looking for the best way to add a textbox to the closable tabs which I can edit from other worker threads.

**EDIT:**
I have added some sample code to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
namespace SampleTabControl
{
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public static Window1 myWindow1;

    public Window1()
    {
      myWindow1 = this;
      InitializeComponent();
      this.AddHandler(CloseableTabItem.CloseTabEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.CloseTab));      
    }

    private void CloseTab(object source, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
      TabItem tabItem = args.Source as TabItem;
      if (tabItem != null)
      {
        TabControl tabControl = tabItem.Parent as TabControl;
        if (tabControl != null)
          tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);
      }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Worker worker = new Worker();

      Thread[] threads = new Thread[1];
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
      {
        TextBox statusBox = new TextBox();

        CloseableTabItem tabItem = new CloseableTabItem();
        tabItem.Content = statusBox;
        MainTab.Items.Add(tabItem);

        int index = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(worker.start));
        threads[i].IsBackground = true;
        threads[i].Start(tabItem);
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the Worker class.

```
namespace SampleTabControl
{
  class Worker
  {
    public CloseableTabItem tabItem;

    public void start(object threadParam)
    {
      tabItem = (CloseableTabItem)threadParam;
      Window1.myWindow1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { tabItem.Header = "TEST"; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
      //Window1.myWindow1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { tabItem.statusBox.Text //statusbox is not accesible here= "THIS IS THE TEXT"; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);

      while (true)
      {
        Console.Beep();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

In the line which I have commented out, statusBox is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your edit, it is clear my original post was not answering the original question.

I think to access the textbox in the way you want you need to cast the tabItem.Content to a Textbox.

Something like below could work

```
TextBox t = tabItem.Content as TextBox;
if (t != null)
    Window1.myWindow1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { t.Text = "THIS IS THE TEXT";}), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

Comment: yes, I know about the dispatcher, but when I add the textbox during runtime to the closable tab, it does not become accessible. I will add some sample code so you can see.

Comment: "TextBox t = tabItem.Content as TextBox;" makes the program crash at runtime.

Comment: I just checked the error message and this is what it says "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." can you tell me how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

WPF cannot modify items that were created on a different thread then the current one

If you haven't already, I would highly recommend that you look into the MVVM design pattern. This separates the UI layer from the business logic layer. Your application becomes your `ViewModel` classes, and the UI layer (Views) are simply a pretty interface that allows users to easily interact with the ViewModels.

This means that all your UI components would share a single thread, while your longer running processes such as retrieving data or crunching numbers can all safely be done on background threads.

For example, you could bind your `TabControl.ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<TabViewModels>`, and when you execute the `AddTabCommand` you would start a new background worker to add a new `TabViewModel` to the `MainViewModel.TabViewModels` collection.

Once the background worker finishes it's job. the UI gets automtaically notified that there is a new item in the collection and will draw the new `TabItem` in the `TabControl` for you, using whatever DataTemplate you specify.